# Find the minimum value of the sum $KP+PQ+QH$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

Be $ABC$ a right triangle in $C$, with $BC=a$ and $AC=b$. In $BC$ is chosen a point $P$ and in $AC$ a point $Q$. Be $K$ and $H$ the perpendicular projections of $P$ and $Q$ respectively over the hypotenuse $AB$

Find the minimum value of the sum $KP+PQ+QH$ with respect to variables $a$ and $b$.

I made a drawing of how the problem should look like:

[image]

But to be honest, i don't see a way to start this problem. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Reflect $A$ and $K$ along $\overline{BC}$ to $A'$ and $K'$, reflect $B$ and $H$ along $\overline{AC}$ to $B'$ and $H'$:

[image]

Comment: With this i see that  $K'PQH'$ has the minimum value when it matches with a common perpendicular between $A'B$ and $AB'$ that goes through $C$, but how to continue with the problem?

Comment: Since $\overline{A'B}$ and $\overline{AB'}$ is parallel, the only condition is that $K', P, Q, H'$ has to colinear, so the choice is not unique. Thus $\overline{K'P} + \overline{PQ} + \overline{QH'}$ is twice the distance from $C$ to $\overline{AB}$. Do you know how to compute this? (Think about two ways to calculate the area of $\triangle ABC$...)